# In Typescript, how can I convert an Array<T> to a Map<K, V> and infer K and V if T is a tuple [K, V] while having compile time protection if it isn't

Tags: arrays, typescript, dictionary, casting, type-inference

The question in the title pretty much says it all. The catch is that `T` cannot be restricted.

Here is what I have tried:

```
class ArrayWrapper<T> {
  constructor(private arr: T[]) {}

  toMap<K, V>() {
    return new Map(<T extends [K, V] ? [K, V][] : never>this.arr);
  }
}
```

I have also tried this:

```
class ArrayWrapper<T> {
  constructor(private arr: T[]) {}

  toMap() {
    return new Map(<T extends [infer K, infer V] ? [K, V][] : never>this.arr);
  }
}
```

In both of the above cases the compiler is giving me a "Conversion of type 'T[]' to ... may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first" error.

So I tried something different and instead of never, I changed the false branch of the conditional type to `never[]`. And this got rid of the compilation error but now when I do something like:

```
class ArrayWrapper<T> {
  constructor(private arr: T[]) {}

  toMap() {
    return new Map(<T extends [infer K, infer V] ? [K, V][] : never[]>this.arr);
  }
}

const notConvertibleToMap = [1, 2, 3];
const convertibleToMap: [number, string][] = [[1, 'one'], [2, 'two'], [3, 'three']];

const arr1 = new ArrayWrapper(notConvertibleToMap);
const map1 = arr1.toMap();

const arr2 = new ArrayWrapper(convertibleToMap);
const map2 = arr2.toMap();
```

The compiler infers Map<unknown, unknown> for both `map1` and `map2`.

What I would like is for the compiler to:

- in the case of `map1`, when trying to call `toMap()` when `T` is not `[K,V]` either give an error or at the very least maybe infer a return type of `never` since this function call is going to throw an error because `T` is not a tuple and the Map constructor is going to throw.
- in the case of `map2`, where `T` IS a `[K, V]`, I want the compiler to correctly infer a type of `Map<K, V>` for `map2`.

Like I said at the beginning, obviously restricting the type of `T` in the class like this

```
class ArrayWrapper<T extends [K, V], K, V> {
  constructor(private arr: T[]) {}

  toMap() {
    return new Map(this.arr);
  }
}
```

would allow for proper inference of `K` and `V`, but I don't want to restrict T. I need this class to accept arrays of any type of contained value `T`.

Additional attempt was made with this:

```
class ArrayWrapper<T> {
  constructor(private arr: T[]) {}

  toMap() {
    if (this.isArrayOfTuple(this.arr)) {
      return new Map(this.arr);
    }

    throw new Error("called toMap() on ArrayWrapper that is not an array of tuples");    
  }

  isArrayOfTuple<K, V>(arr: T[]): arr is [K, V][] {
    return arr[0] instanceof Array && arr[0].length === 2;
  }
}
```

but unfortunately the compiler is complaining over the return type of `isArrayOfTuple`, saying that

```sh
A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.
  Type '[K, V][]' is not assignable to type 'T[]'.
    Type '[K, V]' is not assignable to type 'T'.
      'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '[K, V]'
```

Comment: I think `Map<unknown, unknown>` is fine for the return type if the call is invalid, but you really want the call to give a compiler error itself.  So maybe [this](https://tsplay.dev/wR9ZLW) would work for you? If so I can write up an answer.  If not, can you explain what doesn't work about it (preferably with a [mre])?

Comment: @jcalz this is perfect for what I need. I completely forgot about the possibility of defining `this` as a function parameter. Brilliant. Thank you very much.

Comment: @jcalz if you do decide to write an answer I'll be happy to upvote it and mark it as the correct answer. If you don't feel like writing it, let me know and I'll do it. I'll make sure to give you credit.

Comment: I will definitely do it when I get a chance, hopefully soon

Comment: You could look into [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the compiler to make calling `toMap()` an error if `T` isn't assignable to `[K, V]` for some `K` and `V`, then in some sense it doesn't matter what the output type is in such a case.  It could be `Map<unknown, unknown>` or `Map<never, never>` or anything, as long as the `toMap()` call is a compiler error.  I think you'll end up with a runtime error (you can [wade through the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/keyed-collections.html#sec-map-constructor) if you really care) so the function won't return... the "actual" return type is `never` which can be safely widened to `Map<unknown, unknown>` or anything you want without causing a type safety issue.

Anyway, to make the compiler error happen, you can give `toMap()` a [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-parameters) which requires `this` be of `ArrayWrapper<[any, any]>` or something equivalent.  You could use [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to manually infer `K` and `V` from `T`:

```
toMap(this: ArrayWrapper<[any, any]>) {
    type K = T extends [infer K, any] ? K : never;
    type V = T extends [any, infer V] ? V : never;
    return new Map<K, V>(this.arr);
}
```

but it's even easier to make `toMap()` a [generic method](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) and have `K` and `V` inferred automatically:

```
toMap<K, V>(this: ArrayWrapper<[K, V]>) {
    return new Map<K, V>(this.arr);
}
```

Either method will give you the behavior you're looking for:

```
const arr1 = new ArrayWrapper(notConvertibleToMap);
const map1 = arr1.toMap(); // <-- compiler error
// --------> ~~~~
// The 'this' context of type 'ArrayWrapper<number>' is not assignable to method's 
// 'this' of type 'ArrayWrapper<[unknown, unknown]>'.

const arr2 = new ArrayWrapper(convertibleToMap);
const map2 = arr2.toMap(); // okay
// const map2: Map<number, string>
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCBO8wE8DqSAOGCm8A8AKgHzQDeAUAJDAD2AdhAC7wCuwjN8AFBvAJYA3MI2zQwiAFzQCAbQC6ASjLQAvuSocAsmAwBhegBM+jPvTAgCyHF0YALPhCkIkaTDnwywdZABox3uSIlCkpKRitRAGloAF5paGwADxE6AxgZPjoAM1xoSL8vZDloAH486Ck6bAFcAG4qMIjoADVY+KSUtOhPbz9MnPgW4rLWyuq6hvhsRhZ4OmgqgHdobQw8fJaiG3sIADpxeAV6yjUNGlX1v2atuwcnRBR0HXc8GQ3mwODJ6dn5pZWdJdNtsHPtEEcqGpTrQGIwFjRGPo6DV4CYAEYgbAEc46NoyACMfgATH4AMxyeowpjQGEo9GY7GrKQyOgsAC2aNwfiY-DoAHM5PI8QS-AByejYUVyPwyEnQUWMRY0KUy0liuxTSVyCnqKlwg74tr-ZyPNy4Lh0BFIul8DFYnEYCF66BsnSGuIG3ZaHRcI7QAD0-ugeAAtCGaTQ2Rg+JjBrh4JxyIHoGHU6mSAA-LMZpNBgi2UQKnaiiN0ETJaA0LLQcI4eUm1zPXB4Vkc3BEEsOeH6qB8Pl0MB2ms0F3TWw0AyimC5+W3CAlqs1pqihtPLDNmQsOgAa0tizofi3u5o+8Cot2uvo1NdGHxaLanu9ekMxlMA4sEV9tQDQdD4doUYxrk8aJpesJiIgRJGtgyyrma3C0rg9L2qsTpXnCN5QR6kFeg6X4-pW24oDOzqYVIFytpy8DcswmR8kQ5CkToRL3th8BErhqxIkYJhmB+1h+smNBEcgJHoS6zFouRgKUVy0A8nRRBAA)